# Maven Connection refused to download dependency for junit test

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-3, jboss-arquillian

Brief: I am trying to run a JUnit test but maven fails to download the required dependencies from the central repository giving me the following error for all the dependencies trying to download:

> Nov 29, 2017 4:28:08 PM
>   org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.LogTransferListerer
>   transferFailed WARNING: Failed downloading
>   javassist/javassist/3.16.1-GA/javassist-3.16.1-GA.pom from
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, reason:
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Error transferring
>   file: Connection refused: connect Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors:
>   1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.106 sec <<< FAILURE!

In detail: I am behind a proxy, and this was my first thought, that due to the proxy maven is unable to download the dependencies. Below is the code that i use to download the dependencies

```
WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class).addClass(AlisTestUtil.class)
                .addPackage("com.my.package")
    .addAsLibraries(mavenDependencyResolver.artifact("org.javassist:javassist:3.16.1-GA").resolveAsFiles())
```

**Note**: Maven, does download the dependencies defined in the pom.xml for my project when i do a mvn install, but not when they are requested by the JUnit as seen with the code above.

What i have tried:

1. Added in my maven M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml the proxy settings located under my maven installation (This do surely work as i use the same configuration when building my application and it does download the dependencies from the repository)
2. Added in my .m2/settings.xml the proxy settings
3. Added HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables with the proxy
4. Tried to run the JUnit through eclipse in which i have defined my maven instalation
5. Added in my source code the path to the settings.xml file       **mavenDependencyResolver.configureFrom("C:\Users\myUser\.m2\settings.xml");**
6. Tried to run my mvn command by adding the proxy arguments: ***mvn clean install -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.host.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.host.com-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080***

None of the above steps seem not solve my problem. I start to believe that the problem might not be the proxy after all. I am not sure. Any further suggestions will be appreciated.

PS. I am aware that i can add those dependencies in my pom.xml and set my code to look on my local repository, but this is a solution i want to avoid.

Comment: Why do want to avoid the suggestion solution to put this dependency correctly into the pom file?

Comment: Because this is something i try to avoid. That is the reason i also mentioned it.

Comment: The reason is just cause you are saying so but giving not a good reason for that? Sorry this is not helpful...

Comment: The real question is why shrinkwrap does not take into account the proxy settings. Thats the topic i would like an answer. I am aware of other solutions.